# Store ajax response object in global variable --- Fields get missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm implementing an asynchronous webpage in Grails where I make a call to a controller and render the response as a D3.js network. I stored the object into a global variable for further use. The function worked fine when data is returned. However when I tried to use the object later I found some fields became `undefined`.

```
var similar;

function asynchroNetwork() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "${createLink(controller:'environment', action:'asynchro')}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true
  }).done(function(jsonData) {

      console.log(jsonData);
      //console.log(jsonText);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Done";
      console.log(jsonData.all);

      //set global variable
      similar=jsonData;
      console.log("The object got");
      console.log(similar);
      draw();
    });;
}

function draw(){
  console.log(similar);
  //draw the network based on object
}
```

The controller returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "\u521B\u4E1A" : {
        "nodes" : [{
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u6c88\u9633\u8f9b\u98962\u4e16"
            }
        ],
        "links" : []
    },
    "all" : {
        "nodes" : [{
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "qwe25322570"
            }, {
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u660e\u5fb7\u7b03\u884c"
            }, {
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u6c88\u9633\u53ef\u4e50"
            }, {
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u6c88\u9633\u5f6d\u79c0\u8363"
            }, {
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u6c88\u9633\u738b\u632f\u534e"
            }, {
                "group" : 1,
                "name" : "\u6c88\u9633\u8f9b\u98962\u4e16"
            }
        ],
        "links" : [{
                "value" : 1.0,
                "target" : "\u6c88\u9633\u8f9b\u98962\u4e16",
                "source" : "\u660e\u5fb7\u7b03\u884c"
            }, {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "target" : "\u6c88\u9633\u8f9b\u98962\u4e16",
                "source" : "qwe25322570"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the `draw()` function it uses `similar[all]` to draw a graph. But in the `links` field I see the fields `source` and `target` are all `undefined`, while all fields in the `nodes` are all fine.

I don't think the encoding is the cause because `nodes` also contains UTF8 characters in the fields but none got missing. After the object is passed back from asychronous function the object `similar` is okay, but the next time `draw()` is called, I can see the field `links` go `undefined`.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this problem? I guess it maybe related to nested fields.

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus I put the tag d3js simply because of the json structure. I was wondering if the nested fields could be the cause that when storing the object the references in links just lost connection somehow.

Comment: It works for me! I set up a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaE26a3O3X0iT8yZHK0S?p=preview) demonstrating this. There must be other things going on which cause the error. Try putting together a [mcve] to show where your values get lost.

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks for your Plunker, it's really useful. I tried to extract the logic demonstrating this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CaE26a3O3X0iT8yZHK0S?p=preview) and it works. Actually I asked just to make sure I'm not caught in any ajax "gotchas" that newbies usually meet. I'm trying to dig deeper elsewhere to see how the fields got lost.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing your data as an argument to the draw function? If not, then:

In your ajax callback:

```
similar = jsonData;
draw(similar) //pass the json
```

draw function:

```
function draw(json) {
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: As the first line of the code goes, I put "similar" into a global variable and access it in the draw() function. I'm pretty sure that the 2nd time draw() is invoked the asynchronous call is completed. Are you suggesting the behavior is different when passing the variable as parameter?

Comment: My understanding is that when you send the variable as parameter it is already filled with data BECAUSE it is in the callback of the ajax call which means that draw(similar) will only be called once the ajax call is finished.

Comment: My understanding about ajax is (correct me if I'm wrong), the lines in done() executes in sequence. Therefore if I access the "similar" in draw() the execution will be exactly the same as what you suggest. Also the draw() can be called the 2nd 3rd time elsewhere without passing the jsonData again because I want the jsondata

Comment: OK I get your point. Even I think your code should work fine, but it isn't working. Hmm, how about using the window object? like, set window.similar to the data and access window.similar in your draw function.

Comment: The reason why I used global variable is I want this jsonData to be stored somewhere so that I could use this variable later in other functions without calling my controller again(this part is quite time consuming). Actually, for fear that I didn't make myself clear, the first draw() called in the asychronous function worked as expected. But after I saved it to the global variable, the second access to that variable in draw() from a non-asynchronous function didn't work fine.

Comment: Sorry my last comment wasn't complete.

Comment: Ok, I was understanding it all wrong. Where's your async function and when is it called?

Comment: By async function I meant that $.ajax().done() part. By non-async function i meant `drawClique(){draw(similar.all)}` It just draws a part of the network.

Comment: Where is your non async function? Most probably it is being called before 'done' is executed.